# Ensure that Options for built-in symbols are the original defaults

Tags: options, built-in-symbols, optional-arguments, default

I often create symbols (no args) or functions (with args) in which common options (and styles) are set in body and unique opts within args for managing multiple calls to built-in functions. these spit out a very friendly `Sequence` object. But this still has a problem of creating symbols which in *best practices* should be kept at a bare minimized.

As a novice I recently discovered `SetOptions[symbol, rules]` as it is cleaner, easier on the eyes, and much less prone to error than trailing a trainload of options inside each call to the same function. But one of the best things of all is that no new symbols are created.

As far as I know `Options[symbol]` returns the original Mathematica default values only if `SetOptions[symbol, rules]` was not previously changed.

To achieve what I want, I can only think to begin with a fresh kernel and, before anything loads, run something like this `defopts = Options[symbol] /. List -> Sequence;` then, once done, reset the options with `SetOptions[symbol, defopts]`.

I feel like resetting should be as simple as `ResetOptions[symbol]` (similar to `ResetDirectory`) while returning original non-default settings (for safety) along with the new current settings. If we only wish to view without any reset something like `ResetOptions[symbol, False]`.

So, in short, is there a straightforward programmatic way of retrieving the originally defined default `Options` For built in symbols, after these have been changed with `SetOptions`? Is there an easy way to reset to the original default settings?

Comment: Define your own list of rules (e.g. `myOptions = {PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic}`) and add those to each function call. I find that it simplifies code reuse, since it is immediately clear that some defaults were changed. On the other hand, I find a remote and invisible `SetOptions` less user friendly. Passing a *list* of options, rather than a sequence, shouldn't be a problem, but you could use `Sequence @@ myOptions` if it is. This also does not require a reset, since you didn't change any defaults.

Comment: @MarcoB (1 of 2) i also define symbols (no args) or functions (args) for passing opts and styles. i tend to define all common non-defaults inside function body and call unique opts within args. they spit out a sequence object that always plays friendly. im still an MMA novice so i recently discovered `SetOptions` which i now prefer because no new symbols created. please go to (2 of 2).

Comment: @MarcoB (2 of 2) maybe i am doing something wrong but still works lol.  i hope im not asking for too much. if you have a little free time would you mind in a proper Answer creating a simple concrete example of `SetOptions` on a `Button` setting the easily viewable changed `Options` for `{AutoAction->True, BaseStyle->{16,White,Bold}, Background->Black}`. i promise to give it an upvote and strong consideration for checkmark Accepted.

Comment: @MarcoB if you did the edits they are perfect. i sometimes forget that we're expected to write in a technical report-like fashion which i have years of experience but im also a creative writer (i try to be at least) and a little bleeds in sometimes.

Comment: One idea is to use CloudEvaluate, e.g., `SetOptions[Plot, CloudEvaluate[Options[Plot]]]`

Comment: @Jules I posted an example as an answer. See if I understood your request correctly.

Comment: A different idea is to hide options with `Iconize`. I've noticed this appearing in documentation pages over the past few years. For example: https://wolfram.com/xid/0gfq1n6feq3w-cc2jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example you mentioned in comments, if I am not misunderstanding:

```
buttonOptions = 
  {AutoAction -> True,
   BaseStyle -> {16, White, Bold}, 
   Background -> Black};
Button["Click Here", Echo@RandomPolygon[], buttonOptions]
```

[image: animated GIF showing that the button has the properties requested]

In the example above, the options for button have been set according to the `buttonOptions` variable. `AutoAction` is active as well: in the animation, I am merely hovering over the button and a new action is taken each time.

Comment: yes i do that too. however i always output a `Sequence` object and use args for opts or styles if they differ